# Avoid Line break at end of cmd output?

Tags: powershell, cmd, line-breaks

when I use this command `pwsh -c echo hello` in cmd I get the following output:

```
C:\>pwsh -c echo hello
hello

C:\>
```

I do not get that line break at the end
when I run it on powershell:

```
PS C:\> pwsh -c echo hello
hello
PS C:\>
```

So I think the problem is in cmd. I know this is not such a problem and have an easy fix but I have some programs uses cmd to access powershell and removing that line break is not that fun.
So is there any fix to prevent cmd to add that line ?

Comment: The Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` always outputs an empty line after execution of a command finished before displaying the prompt for next user input. Windows PowerShell `powershell.exe` does not do that. So the empty line is not produced by execution of `pwsh -c echo hello` or just `echo hello`, but by `cmd.exe` itself before printing the prompt `C:\>` in your case. So there is nothing to change. You can see the behavior by running in a command prompt window: `echo Hello Yusef!& echo Is your question answered?` There is no empty line between the two output lines, just above the prompt.

Comment: There is on Super User the question [How to stop the Windows command line from outputting an empty line after each command?](https://superuser.com/questions/97283/how-to-stop-the-windows-command-line-from-outputting-an-empty-line-after-each-co) There could be used `echo Hello Yusef!& set /P =Is your question answered?<nul` to get the two lines output without an empty line because of the prompt text `Is your question answered?` is output without newline character(s) and so the newline character(s) output by `cmd.exe` before the prompt terminates the line with the output prompt text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) has provided the crucial pointers in comments:

- **When executing a command interactively, `cmd.exe` unconditionally appends a a newline (line break) to the command's output**, presumably for readability and perhaps also to ensure that the next prompt always starts on a new line.

  - This applies irrespective of what that command is. In other words: It doesn't matter that your command happens to be a *PowerShell* command.
- **However, that trailing newline does *not* become part of the command's output, therefore *programmatic processing* of a command's output is *not* affected**, such as when you redirect `>` to a file or process the output lines one by one with `for /f`.

  - In other words: for programmatic processing you need *not* remove the trailing newline, because it isn't part of the actual command output.
  - Conversely, if you really need to in effect suppress the trailing newline *for display*, you'll have to *modify the command's output* - if that is even an option - so that the output itself doesn't end in a newline, as shown in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/97308/139307) for `cmd.exe`'s own `echo` command; for PowerShell, you could do `pwsh -c Write-Host -NoNewLine hello`.

---

**Edge case**:

When capturing output from a *batch file* that is running *without `@echo off`* (or with `echo on`) - in which case the trailing newlines  *do* become part of the output - you can filter out empty lines by piping to `findstr /r /v /c:"^$"` (as also shown in the linked answer); e.g.

```
foo.cmd | findstr /r /v /c:"^$"
```

However, note that *all* empty lines are filtered out this way - potentially including *actual* empty lines in the output from commands executed by the batch file.

If preventing that is required, a more sophisticated approach is required, which, however (a) relies on the standard prompt string (e.g., `C:\>`) being used and (b) can still yield false positives:

```
foo.cmd | powershell -nop -c "@($Input) -join \"`n\" -replace '\n(?=[a-z]:\\.*?>)'"
```

Finally note that if you execute the above commands without capturing or redirecting their output, their overall output in the `cmd.exe` console will again have a trailing newline.